# C++ error - "member initializer expression list treated as compound expression"

Tags: c++

I'm getting a C++ compiler error which I'm not familiar with. Probably a really stupid mistake, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Error:

```
test.cpp:27: error: member initializer expression list treated as compound expression
test.cpp:27: warning: left-hand operand of comma has no effect
test.cpp:27: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const Bar&’ from expression of type ‘int’
```

Code:

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2
  3 class Foo {
  4 public:
  5         Foo(float f) :
  6                 m_f(f)
  7         {}
  8
  9         float m_f;
 10 };
 11
 12 class Bar {
 13 public:
 14         Bar(const Foo& foo, int i) :
 15                 m_foo(foo),
 16                 m_i(i)
 17         {}
 18
 19         const Foo& m_foo;
 20         int m_i;
 21 };
 22
 23
 24 class Baz {
 25 public:
 26         Baz(const Foo& foo, int a) :
 27                 m_bar(foo, a)
 28         {}
 29
 30         const Bar& m_bar;
 31 };
 32
 33 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 34         Foo a(3.14);
 35         Baz b(a, 5.0);
 36
 37         std::cout << b.m_bar.m_i << " " << b.m_bar.m_foo.m_f << std::endl;
 38
 39         return 0;
 40 }
```

Note:
  It looks like the compiler is evaluating the commas in line 27 like here:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/co.htm

**edit:**
Okay, I understand the problem as Alan explained it. Now, for extra imaginary points, can someone explain how the compiler (g++) came up with the error message it gave?

Comment: How did g++ come up with it's error message? No idea.

Sun Studio gives this error

    line 27: Error: Too many initializers for m_bar.

It's a little more informative.  The short answer is that a lot of compilers error messages tend to be a little hard to read.

Comment: **For the extra points:** It came up with this error because the code is trying to construct a `Bar` with a constructor of `(foo,a)` . The error message is telling you the foo will be ignored and that it can't convert the `int a` into a Bar.  I know this is an ancient question, but what you have marked as the answer is incorrect and misleading. I posted the code on how you would leave your declaration of `m_bar` alone and get this to compile.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

m_bar is a reference, so you can't construct one.

As others have noted, you can initialise references with the object it refers to,  but you can't construct one like you're trying to do.

Change line 30 to

```
const Bar m_bar
```

and it'll compile / run properly.

Answer (score 5):

m_bar is declared as a "const reference" and therefore can't be instantiated with the constructor you've supplied.

Consider making m_bar a member, or passing a pre-constructed Bar object to the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

You can see the problem much more clearly in the following code:

```
struct B {
    B( int a, int x  ) {}
};

int main() {
    const B & b( 1, 2);
}
```

which produces the following errors with g++:

```
t.cpp: In function 'int main()':
t.cpp:6: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
t.cpp:6: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const B&' from expression of type int'
```

VC++ 6.0 gives the even more gnomic error:

```
 error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
```

Simply put, you can't initialise references like that.

Answer (score 0):

(Edit: See the comments)
Although this question is old, for future readers I will point out that the item marked as an answer is not correct. A reference can indeed be constructed.

In an initializer line, the code `m_bar(foo, a)` is trying to use `(foo,a)` as a constructor for m_bar. The error tells you that `foo` will be ignored and you can't construct a Bar out of  `int a`. The following correct syntax will compile error free:

```
m_bar (*new Bar(foo,a))
```

Comment: The answer marked as correct is most certainly correct! While a reference **can** be constructed, it doesn't mean it **should**! (Though you're on the right track concerning the compiler message, I'll grant you that!)

Comment: @Tod I like your line of thought (i.e. that the comma can be interpreted as part of expression and not as delimiter between two parameters) - your compiler could perhaps give such hint. But still I can't agrre that your example shows that 'a refeence can be constructed'. What you construct (new Bar(foo, a)) is a temporary. The reference then only binds to this temporary (what is something we usuually do not want to do).