# C++ constructor error

Tags: c++, sdl

Im getting the following error for the piece of code below : "expression list treated as compound expression" . I can't find out whats wrong?

```
Shoot::Shoot() :
    io( IOManager::getInstance() ),
    count(0),
    locX(0),
    locY(0),
    objWidth(0),
    objHeight(0),
    clock( Clock::getInstance() ),
    ticks(0),
    bulletSurface(io.loadAndSet("images/bullet.bmp", true)), 
    bulletFrame(bulletSurface, 30, 30, 0, 0),
    thebullet(Vector2f(700,760), Vector2f(20,45), "bullet" , &bulletFrame)
           {

           }
```

DEclarations :

```
    private :

          const IOManager& io;
          int count;

          int locX;
          int locY;
          unsigned objWidth;
          unsigned objHeight;
          Clock& clock; 
          unsigned ticks;
          SDL_Surface *bulletSurface;
          Frame bulletFrame;
          Sprite *thebullet;
          Shoot(const Shoot&);
          Shoot& operator=(const Shoot&);
```

Comment: I've modified the whitespace in your code snippet to make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: Take a look at this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877107/c-error-member-initializer-expression-list-treated-as-compound-expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `thebullet` is a pointer, but you're trying to initialise it with `Vector2f(700,760), Vector2f(20,45), "bullet" , &bulletFrame`.

My guess is that you want `thebullet(new Bullet(...))`.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. Although if it is, I strongly recommend that you don't use raw pointers and manual memory management, and instead investigate smart pointers.</sub>

Comment: Looks like `thebullet(new Sprite(...))` might do it (but that's just making an assumption about what a `Sprite` might be).